# Allow users of a certain group to login with Azure AD B2C

Tags: authentication, azure-ad-b2c

I am using Azure AD B2C and I want a group based user distribution for my application. Lets say I have two subdomains `subA.myapp.com` and `subB.myapp.com`. On the other hand, I have two groups `subA` and `subB`in Azure B2C. Now a user wants to signin to `subA.myapp.com`, but is not a member of group `subA`, I would like to deny the user to sign in.

I know that Azure B2C does not include group info in the access token. So I will actually use Graph API to get the group membership of the user. But I am not quite sure if there is an appropriate event where I could intercept the validation process and manually deny a user to sign-in. Also, I thought I could use one of the `*Validator` methods of `TokenValidationParameters` but not sure which one.

I have read [Authorize By Group in Azure Active Directory B2C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40302231). My problem is different because that problem is trying to protect only some actions based on group memberships, I want to prevent the whole login process to fail based on group membership.

Comment: Which authentication middleware are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Authorize By Group in Azure Active Directory B2C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40302231/authorize-by-group-in-azure-active-directory-b2c)

Comment: check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40302231/authorize-by-group-in-azure-active-directory-b2c)

Comment: @ChrisPadgett: OpenIdConnectAuthenticationMiddleware

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [ValidationTechnicalProfile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-rest-api-validation-custom) on a page created by the SelfAssertedAttributeProvider technical profile. Using the validation technical profile, you can first authenticate the user, and then call a Rest API that can look up users group membership and return a successfull/fail response.

If the response is successful, the flow will continue. If it's a failure, an error will be shown to the user.