# How to include roles in issued token when using multi-tenant Azure AD (or Google) with Azure AD B2C?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, azure-ad-b2c

My scenario is similar (probably duplicated with [How to include roles in issued token when using multi-tenant Azure AD with Azure AD B2C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72645617/how-to-include-roles-in-issued-token-when-using-multi-tenant-azure-ad-with-azure))
Even though I still have to open this question, I can not successfully apply the answer of the origin question and don't know how to contact the author.
So this is my case:

1. I set up [sign-in for multi-tenant Azure Active Directory using custom policies in Azure Active Directory B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-multi-tenant?pivots=b2c-custom-policy) and [with a Google account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-google?pivots=b2c-custom-policy)
2. I'm able to create my custom roles by editing the Manifest of the app.
   [The App's manifest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JgW9o.png)
3. I'm able to add users and assign roles to them
   [Add user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5LZP5.png)
   [Assign role](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0vuz.png)
4. Now what I want is to return the roles object within the issued token, something like this
   `{ ... "roles": [ "role1", "role2" ], ... }`
   but currently, after following the instruction of the answer of the original question, the token is unchanged and the "roles" object is not found.
   [Currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvmzq.png)

What I've tried:

1. As I mentioned earlier, I followed the instruction of the original question, updated the XML files, and updated them in the Identity Exp Framework, but still failed.
2. I tried to grant the application as higher permission as possible but still failed.
3. Searched around for more questions/answers like this but there are none.
4. Even in the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/supported-azure-ad-features), MS confirms that "Roles are not supported with consumer accounts", but somehow, in the original question, there is a solution to retrieve the roles in the issued token.