# How to pass a bearer token with Azure AD?

Tags: typescript, azure, sharepoint, azure-active-directory

I have developed a Sharepoint WebPart that contains a call to an external API.

I would like to know how can I call this external API using Azure AD Security. Are there any way to add a bearer token in the call with the value retrieved by Azure?.

Somebody have any idea, how it works?.

I have read a lot of documentation about this but the majority of the examples are unclear .

Regards

Comment: here's a good start: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/gettingstarted/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your external API should be protected by Azure AD. You can refer to the sample  [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/4-WebApp-your-API/4-1-MyOrg).

Then you need to get an access token, just pass the access token in the request header when call the external API.

It should be something like

[image]

Reference:

[Azure REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/gettingstarted/)

Comment: Hi Tony, Thanks for your help.  How can  I get the access token in the WebPart?. I have developed this WebPart with TypeScript

Comment: @vcima You can refer to the answer here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55408226/getting-and-using-microsoft-graph-token-in-angular-6-to-get-group-membership-fro

Comment: Hi Tony-Ju, and the last question: Can I do something like this? 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60754927/how-to-securize-redirection-with-azure-ad-in-a-webpart