# One ASP.NET Core 2.2 Web API app Using Multiple Client IDs (Application IDs) of Azure AD B2C

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, openid-connect, azure-ad-b2c, asp.net-core-2.2

I have ASP.NET 2.2 Web API App using Azure AD B2C for auth

I have three roles requirements. Each role has different Azure AD B2C policies and a user can have one and only one role.

Currently adding roles with B2C is convoluted:

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/10123836-get-user-membership-groups-in-the-claims-with-ad-b

[Authorize By Group in Azure Active Directory B2C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40302231/authorize-by-group-in-azure-active-directory-b2c)

And to solve the role and policies per role, I am considering having multiple Azure AD B2C Applications within one ASP.NET Core Web API.

My ASP.NET Config for Azure AD B2C in the `Startup.cs` looks as follow:

```
services.AddAuthentication(AzureADB2CDefaults.JwtBearerAuthenticationScheme)
.AddAzureADB2CBearer(o => Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", o));
```

**Is having multiple Azure AD B2C ClientIDs (Application IDs) possible in ASP.NET Core? Are there libraries to do so? Do you have a better suggestion?**

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to get user's group information in one of the notification function s(for example , SecurityTokenValidated) and add claim to the ClaimsPrincipal. You can click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41420184/5751404) for code sample .

If you register multi applications , if using [OAuth 2.0 code grant flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-protocols-oauth-code) , when redirecting user to Azure AD's login page you should provide the client id , how do you know which client id you should use before knowing who is the current user ? Unless you create extra page to let user choose which client he want to login , and then add an `OpenIdConnectEvents` handler for the `OnRedirectToIdentityProvider` event and replace the ClientId property there .

Comment: You've posted the same link that I've posted. Thank you for the extra analysis, which is useful, but doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @Adam `Is having multiple Azure AD B2C ClientIDs (Application IDs) possible in ASP.NET Core` you need add a page to let user choose which client he want to use and in `OnRedirectToIdentityProvider ` to modify the client id .`Do you have a better suggestion` use microsoft graph to get group information and add to user claim .