# Adding roles to Angular SPA and MSAL when using using Azure AD B2C

Tags: angular, openid-connect, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api, msal.js

Using Angular 7 with MSAL.js and Azure AD B2C.

Implementing a role-based authentication is not directly supported by Azure AD B2C and requires the use of Azure Ad Graph API.

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/10123836-get-user-membership-groups-in-the-claims-with-ad-b

[Authorize By Group in Azure Active Directory B2C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40302231/authorize-by-group-in-azure-active-directory-b2c)

Is there a way to use MSAL with Azure AD Graph API to support roles (through claims or Azure AD B2C security groups)?

Comment: Whoever voted this to close as "Too Broad" and gave a down vote: Asking for "a way" out of nothing on the Internet for this is not too broad. I would appreciate if you comment why you think it is too broad after viewing and reading the supplied links.

Comment: Hi Adam, did you ever manage to find something out about this?

Comment: @Andrew No, couldn't find any

Answer (score 0):

You can add roles in the manifest of an application registration, that way you will get a roles claim with those roles defined.

Here is an article on how to create roles: [How to add app roles in AAD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps).

If you are using groups instead you can associate a role to each group.

Comment: This is regarding Azure AD *B2C* , the referenced article is for Azure AD