# Azure AD - return roles and groups in token SPA application

Tags: azure, authentication, .net-core, azure-active-directory, roles

I created an Angular application with Implicit Grant Flow for authentication and a Web Api in .Net Core 3.1 following this tutorial: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-javascript-angular-spa-aspnetcore-webapi

The problem is: I need to return the roles and/or groups of the logged User within the Bearer Token to authorize my API, but I'm not being able to do so.

I added the roles to the App Registrations Manifest [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QcSh.png), added the claim 'groups' in the [Token Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IEgMU.png) menu and set the ["User assignment required?"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDk16.png) as yes in my Enterprise App Configuration.

Even with all these configurations, I'm not able to return the roles/groups claims in the bearer token.

Example of the token the authentication returns:

```
  {
  "ver": "2.0",
  "iss": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/9188040d-6c67-4c5b-b112-36a304b66dad/v2.0",
  "sub": "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABTOBMzzWB5LS36oSmQMgyc",
  "aud": "ecb5e87f-6f34-4f05-8e8d-8d6149178926",
  "exp": 1597173984,
  "iat": 1597170084,
  "nbf": 1597170084,
  "name": "name",
  "preferred_username": "email@outlook.com",
  "oid": "00000000-0000-0000-fa54-d112egdce65a",
  "tid": "9188040d-6c67-4c5b-b112-36a304b643ad",
  "azp": "edeb4b7d-9cac-4f3b-a21d-ead77993689e",
  "scp": "access_as_user",
  "azpacr": "0",
  "aio": "DYNhHjG*PSY1ceuC11yaLYcLta8zh49iA!l2UCbCsH9QlaUkEHVQ4paQFRmb!qv7J6yTbAQItGWDgCW9UgUipz4Xnma*DOkFFDNIZ5lkffThD*ie91XMzZIoPhUPwNHOt5dLrw3VASE2WCvJfvDFOQk$"
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is there any other way to authorize the logged user in a SPA Application, return the token with the roles and groups and send it to the Web Api?

Comment: I've faced this issue many times. Your API needs to retrieve the groups and include in the token.

Comment: take a look on this https://stackoverflow.com/a/60022121/1384539

Comment: You have to define the roles in the Manifest json. App Registration / Manifest.
Here is a (bit old) tutorial how to create and assigns roles 
https://joonasw.net/view/defining-permissions-and-roles-in-aad

Comment: @ZsoltBendes I already added the roles to the Manifest and assined them to the users, but they are not returned in the Token after the login.

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio that link is not very helpful as I am trying to retrieve the roles and groups from a SPA application and not from a Asp Net MVC.

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio does not matter if it is a SPA or server side request. You can request a token from client and from server side as well. If you already have the code to fetch a token from AAD you just need to edit the manifest and assign the user to the role. The token will have a new array with roles in it.

Comment: usually it will be empty as a user can have multiple groups and the token has a fixed length. You need query it from Azure ad

Comment: Please refer to this [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-javascript-angular-spa-dotnetcore-webapi-roles-groups/tree/master/chapter1) it may help you

Answer (score 0):

You should add the App Role into the manifest of the **service app (TodoListAPI)** rather than the **client app (TodoListSPA)**.

Don't forget the assign the App Role to the users.

This should be able to fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Hi You need go to azure ad -> app registrations -> your app -> taken configuration -> Add Groups Claim -> then select Security groups checkbox. Save. Then log out log in again and should be in taken under groups.