# How can I use Custom Roles on Azure Ad B2C?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

My API needs three types of users and I want to manage it with custom role definitions. Is it possible to create roles on Azure B2c then assign these roles to the users by Microsoft Graph API?

Comment: https://mrochon.azurewebsites.net/2019/05/06/using-groups-in-azure-ad-b2c/

Comment: Thanks but it seems very old answer. I think there is built-in, better solution on azure ad b2c.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Authorize By Group in Azure Active Directory B2C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40302231/authorize-by-group-in-azure-active-directory-b2c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Am working toward the same goal , so here is what I found until this moment:

- Use Custom Policies with Identity Esperience Framework (IEF) : Here is an [example of custom policies on RBAC example](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/relying-party-rbac) :
- Manually call the Graph API ( using msal library ) with the objectId of the connected user and an access token in order to get the groups to which the user belong : In this case you will create a group for each role , affect the users to the right groups based on their role, by finding the users group , u know what's his role , here is an [example](https://damienbod.com/2021/09/06/using-azure-security-groups-in-asp-net-core-with-an-azure-b2c-identity-provider/) of implementing this kind of authorization on .Net5 web api and web App.

Didn' find anything related to managing users access with roles , so if you found any , do not hesitate to share . Thanks

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I did the second one for a while before, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an extension attribute called `extension_role`, and use Graph API to write the role name to this attribute.

Example on how to create and write to the extension attribute [here](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/user-migration/blob/master/seamless-account-migration/script/Pre-MigrationHelper.ps1).

Then in AAD B2C custom policy, read the extension attribute and insert it into the token.

Eg, read the attribute on sign in/up:

```xml
        <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId">
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="Operation">Read</Item>
            <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">true</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" Required="true" />
          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_role" />
          </OutputClaims>
          <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-Common" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
```

Insert into token:

```xml
  <RelyingParty>
    <DefaultUserJourney ReferenceId="SignUpOrSignIn" />
    <TechnicalProfile Id="PolicyProfile">
      <DisplayName>PolicyProfile</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_role" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" PartnerClaimType="sub"/>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="tenantId" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" DefaultValue="{Policy:TenantObjectId}" />

      </OutputClaims>
      <SubjectNamingInfo ClaimType="sub" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </RelyingParty>
```